# Thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) FATAL EXCEPTION:Main

Tags: android, exception

I'm still very new to this so the solution is probably obvious.
Any way I'm trying to make the buttons in this app open new activities but when I run it, forcecloses. Does anyone know what's wrong? I was going to use something called list view but that didn't use the XML I made for the class.

```
package com.example.musicbynumbers;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainMenu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {
    Button majScales, minHarm, minMel;
    ImageButton mainMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        mainMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagelogo);
        majScales = (Button) findViewById(R.id.majorscalesb);


    }




         @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(arg0.getId()){
                case R.id.imagelogo:
                    Intent i =  new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case R.id.majorscalesb:
                    Intent j = new Intent(MainMenu.this, majorScales.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;}

    }

}
```

Layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="80"
    tools:context=".MainMenu"

     >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagelogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/majorscalesb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="Major Scales"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minormelodicb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="Minor Melodic Scales" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minorharmonicb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="Minor Harmonic Scales" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/arpeggiosb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="Arpeggios"
        android:gravity="center" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/chromaticscalesb"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="10"
          android:text="Chromatic Scales"
          android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contraryb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="Contrary Motion"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aboutb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="About" 
        android:gravity="center"
        >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.musicbynumbers"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.musicbynumbers.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.musicbynumbers.majorScales"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.musicbynumbers.majorScales" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix your code by this

```
ImageButton mainMenu;

mainMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagelogo);
```

UPDATE:

OK, I found the error. you forgot to set the `OnClickListener` for every `Button` or `ImageButton`

try this

```
    majScales.setOnClickListener(this);
    mainMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Thank you didn't realize I had Made so many mistakes. Now that it isn't crashing the buttons aren't working any ideas? I'll update the code.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you spelled the intent incorrectly.

```
Intent j = new Intent("com.exapmle.muscibynumbers.majorScales");
```

should be

```
Intent j = new Intent("com.example.musicbynumbers.majorScales");
```

For another, you have two applications defined.

Without the stack trace it's hard to know what else might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks but shouldn't eclipse have noticed that and put a red mark beside it?

Comment: No. It's not a syntax error. That's a perfectly valid string.